# Populate Input based on another field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 1 field that will be used for the users name, and another that will be used for the users URL

so if a user types `john smith` into the name input, i would like to automatically populate the URL input with `john-smith` since the url will end up being `/personal-trainer-directory/john-smith`

how do I do this automatically so the user doesnt have to fill out the url field?

Here is an example but there is some ExpressionEngine code, thats why there are curly brackets, but I figure this is more related to the code instead of the CMS so posting this here.

this is what I currently have:

```
<div class="formsection clearfix">
<label for="title">Name</label>
<span class="directions">The name you want to be displayed in your listing.</span>
<input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="{title}" size="50" maxlength="100">
</div>

<div class="formsection clearfix">
<label for="url_title">URL Title</label>
<span class="directions">Put a dash between first and last name. example: "john-smith"</span>
<input type="text" name="url_title" id="url_title" value="{url_title}" maxlength="75" size="50">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#title").change( function () {
    $('#url_title').val('/personal-trainer-directory/'+$(this).val().toLowerCase().replace(/ +/g, '-').trim());
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rccb8/)**

Comment: thanks! this brought me the closest! I jsut want to have the name show up with the dash in between is this part correct: `$('#url_title').val(''+$(this).val().toLowerCase().replace(/ +/g, '-').trim());` ?

Comment: Yes, and you can get rid of the `''+` part.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
$(function(){
    $("#title").blur(function(){
        $("#url_title").val('/personal-trainer-directory/' + $(this).val());
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmatseykanets/kvfJA/)

or if you want it to be populated as you type

```
$(function(){
    $("#title").keyup(function(){
        $("#url_title").val('/personal-trainer-directory/' + $(this).val());
    });
```

});
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmatseykanets/6Tzvq/)